# Inject code in a PHP closure

Tags: php, oop, closures

I have an already defined closure and I want to inject code inside when I execute it.
Here is an example:

```
$predefined = "print 'my predefined injected code<br />';";
$closure = function () {
  print 'hello<br />';
};
call_user_func_array($closure, array());
// output : hello
```

I want to mix 2 codes : a predefined one and the closure's one.
After modification, I want my closure to look like this

```
$closure = function () {
  print 'my predefined injected code<br />';
  print 'hello<br />';
};
```

Is it possible to insert some code in the closure before executing it ?

Note: I can not use "create_function" that take the code as a string, so can be modified easily. The closures are already defined and are defined in a certain way (through a function that take a callback arg, not a string arg).

Thanks for your help.

---

EDIT:

Here is the  solution

```
function hackClosure($closure, $inject_code)
{
    $reflection = new ReflectionFunction($closure);
    $tmp = $reflection->getParameters();
    $args = array();
    foreach ($tmp as $a) array_push($args, '$'.$a->getName() . ($a->isDefaultValueAvailable() ? '=\''.$a->getDefaultValue().'\'' : ''));
    $file = new SplFileObject($reflection->getFileName());
    $file->seek($reflection->getStartLine()-1);
    $code = '';
    while ($file->key() < $reflection->getEndLine())
    {
        $code .= $file->current();
        $file->next();
    }
    $start = strpos($code, '{')+1;
    $end = strrpos($code, '}');
    return create_function(implode(', ', $args), substr($code, $start, $end - $start) . $inject_code);
}

$theClosure = function () { print 'something'; };

$inject_code = "print ' to say';";

$func = hackClosure($theClosure, $inject_code);
$func();
```

It renders

```
something to say
```

instead of

```
something
```

Comment: Add it as a solution and accept it. Also some comments would be nice.

Answer (score 8):

You can't directly inject it.  However, you can wrap it.

```
$newClosure = function() use ($closure) {
    print 'my predefined injected code<br />';
    $closure();
};
```

Also, there's no need to use `call_user_func_array` since you're not passing any arguments.  Just call `$closure();`

Also, you could build a wrapper to get a new closure:

```
$creator = function($closure) {
    return function() use ($closure) {
        print 'my predefined injected code<br />';
        $closure();
    };
};

$newClosure = $creator($closure);
$newClosure();
```

Comment: That is a good point but the result is that the "print 'my predefined injected code<br />';" is outside the closure. I want it to be inside.

Comment: @Pierre: I said at the top of the question you can't do that.  Once the closure is created, you can't modify it.  But you can wrap it so that your code gets executed before or after it...

Comment: thank you for your answer, I am working on a <dirty> solution that works fine for me and uses Reflection.

Comment: @PierreL: that doesn't make sense. Your reflection code creates and returns a new function. This answer also creates and returns a new function. What's the difference?

Comment: One difference is that you can't access variables that the Closure closes over.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like this:

```
$closure = function($optionalcode = null) {
    print('blah blah blah');
    if (!is_null($optionalcode)) { eval($optionalcode); }
    print('blah blah blah');
}

$closure("print('yoohoo!');");
```

However, `eval()` is evil and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Well, my closure are user defined, I can not modify the way they are written.

Comment: The result is that the "print 'my predefined injected code<br />';" is outside the closure. I want it to be inside the closure

Comment: You should definitely avoid using eval().

Comment: With the introduction of closures, the need for `eval` is basically nil.  Just pass in the closure, and do a check `if (is_callable($optionalcode)) { $optionalcode(); }`

Answer (score -1):

Is't this what you are looking for ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: Eval takes a String as a parameter. I only have the already defined closure (so a "variable"), not the "string of the code of the closure".

Comment: [How do I write a good answer to a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)