# Way to inject variables into existing closure scope?

Tags: php, reflection, closures

is there a way to "inject" a variable into the scope of a closure? what i'm trying to do is something like that:

```
$c = function($x){echo $x.$y;};
$y = 'RLY?';
$c = inject_var($c,$y);
$c('O ');
```

another way could be like this:

```
$c = function($x){echo $x.$y;};
$c = extend_paramlist($c,'y');
$c('O ','RLY?');
```

i think [Inject code in a PHP closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143127/inject-code-in-a-php-closure) is a way, but is there an easier way as i just want to extend the parameter list of the closure, not the code. I'm aware of use(), but i want to "inject" the variable after the closure is defined and i don't want to global.

Comment: This question makes me want to cry. Please say this is for hacking an existing closed library and not an attempt to actually write new code.

Comment: @pst: He definitely is writing new code. Or the original writer of the code was seriously braindamaged, because he used variables in a closure, which aren't passed to it ;)

Comment: yep, it's an attempt to actually write new code :-) i'm playing around and want to check ways of using closures.

Answer (score 19):

Maybe what you want is the `use` clause of a closure:

```
$y = 'RLY?';
$c = function($x) use($y) { echo $x.$y; };
$c('O ');
```

Or, if you really want to extend the argument list, do it properly:

```
$c = function($x,$y){ 
        $f = function($x) use($y) {echo $x.$y; };
        $f($x);
     };
$c('O ','RLY?');
```

Comment: first: thx for the missing ; :-) . as i said, the closure is already defined. i can't use use() afaik.

Comment: @user601187, Sorry, it is impossible then. The `$y` in your closure is a local (and uninitialized) variable. If PHP was strictly typed, that would be a compile-time error.